# NCAlgebra 6.0.2 fails to compute the gradient of the trace of a simple quadratic product

Tags: bugs, ncalgebra

`NCAlgebra` version `6.0.2` fails to compute the gradient of the trace of a quadratic product. Works fine in version `5.0.6final`.
Am I missing something?

```
Mathematica 13.3.1 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2023 Wolfram Research, Inc.
```

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/blob/master/NCAlgebra-6.0.2.paclet?raw=true"];
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`
<< NCDiff`

NCGrad[tr[x**tp[x]], x]
```

```
NCPolynomial::NotPolynomial: Expression is not an nc polynomial.
NCGrad::Failed: Do not know how to calculate NCGrad. Expression tr[x ** tp[x]] is most likely not rational or invalid.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in v6.0.3.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and contribution.

Comment: My pleasure. There was a minor glitch in the packaging so you might want to download the latest v6.0.3 version just to be sure you get the full functionality.